# Как задать цвет текста, чтобы он не изменялся при ночном режиме смартфон?

Tags: java, android, themes

я написал приложение на языке Java в андроид студио. Через некоторое время мне стали писать, что в приложении не отображаются некоторые тексты. Я посмотрел скриншоты и узнал, что это происходит при ночном режиме самого смартфон. И так мой вопрос:как заранее узнать на какой цвет будет меняться цвет текста при ночном режиме и можно ли сделать так чтобы не менялся цвет текста при ночном режиме?

Comment: Уберите в программе возможность самопроизвольно менять цвета при переключении дня и ночи. Это в темах вроде

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но в андроид студио в темах нет такой функции. Опишите действия по подробнее, пожалуйста-))

Comment: @АзимджонХакимов добавьте файл, например, color-text.xml и напишите в него нужный вам цвет, сделайте копию и положите в папку values-night там задайте цвет для ночного режима или просто используйте параметр <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>

Comment: Темы в манифесте

Comment: Если пользователь хочет ночной режим - дайте. Очень неприятно когда всё в тёмных тонах и только одна поделка режет глаз - это может побудить пользователя заменить её приложением с более приятным интерфейсом. Скорее всего вы принудительно задали фон, который сливается с текстом - сделайте альтернативный для ночного режима.

Answer (score 0):

Данная проблема была решена путём удаления в ресурсах theme.xml(night) и добавления в theme.xml следующего кода:

```html
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="Q">false</item>
```

Эта строчка кода означает что начиная с андроид Q функция затемнения экрана не разрешена в данном приложении.